# Construct a ciruct from a graph that outputs 1 if the graph has an independent set

Tags: algorithm, graph, reduction, np, circuit-diagram

Let's say I have a graph,

[image]

and from this graph I want to create a circuit K whose inputs can be set so that K outputs true iff the graph has an independent set of size ≥2.
I've seen some decent stuff on the internet / youtube about how to go about this. But I was wondering if there is a standard set of steps one should follow on how to do this.

My thought process was sort of: Have the circuit take edges as input, and output 1 (true) if at least one edge is missing (as this edge is an independent set).

But if i'm being honest i'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Please clarify: your only circuit in this graph is ABC, which does not contain any independent set of two nodes.  The graph as a whole has only one such set, {B, D}, but those are not part of any circuit.

Comment: Also, please discuss your work so far; your empty allusion to your research doesn't help *us* focus the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct in concept, but there's an even easier way: count the edges in the graph.  For N nodes, if |E| < N * (N-1) / 2, then you have at least one independent set of size >= 2.  All it takes is one missing edge, as you've noted.

To find the *largest* independent set, there's a transformation trick that's relatively easy in concept: Invert the graph:  switch all non-edges and edges.  For instance, your posted graph contains 4 of the possible 6 edges.  Invert this, so your graph edges are only `DB` and `DC`.

Take the resulting graph and find the largest clique (there's plenty of material on this).  That largest clique is the largest independent graph.